# Why cant I change the session timeout for Patron when using Faraday in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am trying to change the connection timeouts for HTTP requests done with Faraday using Patron as the adapter.

I try to change the timeout using the default_connections_options in my program as follows:

```
Faraday.default_connection_options.request.timeout = 10
```

The problem is that I still experience 5000 ms (Patron default) timeouts when making requests.

```
/Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/patron-0.6.5/lib/patron/session.rb:321:in `handle_request': Operation timed out after 5003 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (Faraday::TimeoutError)
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/patron-0.6.5/lib/patron/session.rb:321:in `request'
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:33:in `call'
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
from /Users/finihoge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or how I can change the default session timeouts in Patron when I am using it as an adapter in Faraday?

Comment: Maybe the default connection timeout is the timeout for the default adapter. Where do you set Patron as an adapter?